# Most supported/reliable package to use to generate a thumbnail from an uploaded video?

Tags: python, django

I have a Post model with a `video` field for video a user uploads in their post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    video = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True)
    thumbnail = #something
```

Then in my view when the video is being uploaded:

```
def post(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        form_post = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form_post.is_valid():
            instance = form_post.save(commit=False)
            instance.thumnnail = #something
            instance.save()
```

What is the best package or method for creating a thumbnail from the uploaded video? And where in the code would I generate the thumbnail?

Answer (score 0):

If you want thumbnail generation check django-videokit https://github.com/pstreck/django-videokit